# Identify duplicated values and append a unique string to them

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"my_col": ["one","two","two","one","two","one","one"]})

  my_col
0    one
1    two
2    two
3    one
4    two
5    one
6    one
```

I would like append a string on the duplicated values with their duplicate count. Here is what I mean:

```
   my_col
0  one_0
1  two_0
2  two_1
3  one_1
4  two_2
5  one_2
6  one_3
```

I know I could do something like df.groupby('my_col').apply(my_function_to_do_this) with something like this :

```
def my_function_to_do_this(group: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    str_to_append = pd.Series(range(group.shape[0]), index=group.index).astype(str)
    group["my_col"] += "_" + str_to_append
    return group
```

but that's quite slow on a large DataFrame with a lot of small groups of like 4 rows maximum.

I'm trying to find a faster approach if any.

Many thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, convert to strings and add to original with [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].str.cat(df.groupby('my_col').cumcount().astype(str), sep='_')
print (df)
  my_col
0  one_0
1  two_0
2  two_1
3  one_1
4  two_2
5  one_2
6  one_3
```

Or join by `+`:

```
df['my_col'] += '_' +  df.groupby('my_col').cumcount().astype(str)
#longer version
#df['my_col'] = df['my_col'] + '_' +  df.groupby('my_col').cumcount().astype(str)
```

Comment: Nice, forgot about this coumcount(), thank you very much !